# Error con datepicker yearRange materialize

Tags: datepicker, jquery-datepicker

Tengo un datepicker que me funciona perfectamente lo único que quiero agregarle es un "yearRange: "2002:2012"" para que aparezcan los años que yo le indique en la scroll por ejemplo, pero al hacerlo y recargar al mostrar mi datapicker donde debería mostrar el año se elimina osea en vez de aparecer "2018" y al pincharlo sale es scroll para seleccionar el año sale en blanco, únicamente agregando el yearRange:

```
$(function() {
$('#fecha').datepicker({
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    firstDay: 1,
    i18n: {
        months: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
        monthsShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
        weekdays: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
        weekdaysShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
        weekdaysAbbrev: ['D','L','M','M','J','V','S'],
        yearRange: "2002:2012",
    }
});
```

al colocarlo asi es que me da ese error :

```
$(function() {
$('#fecha').datepicker({
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    yearRange: "2002:2012",
    firstDay: 1,
    i18n: {
        months: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
        monthsShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
        weekdays: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
        weekdaysShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
        weekdaysAbbrev: ['D','L','M','M','J','V','S'],
        yearRange: "2002:2012",
    }
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución el datepicker de materialize tiene algunas variables y sintaxis distintos las cuales hay que leer la documentación detalladamente para saber como se emplea, en este caso el yearRange debe quedar de esta manera:

`$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
yearRange: [1950,2005], 
changeMonth: true, 
changeYear: true, });`

ademas de agregar el changeMounth y changeYear en true.